# 403 forbiden on index.php ; again :c

Tags: apache2

I have a problem with apache configuration which don't want to run php :
When I access localhost (index.html) I get what I want but when I run index.php with some simple code inside :  I get "403 forbidden".
I tried chmod 777 on index.php (don't kill me please :p ) but nothing changes.
I googled my problem, tried different configurations...
Thanks for any help c:

Comment: Did you install `libapache2-mod-php<your-php-version>`

Comment: Run `apachectl -M | grep php`

Comment: Yes I have installed libapache-mod-php7.0. This is what the command shows
`iskog@iskog-server:/var/mail$ apachectl -M | grep php
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
 php7_module (shared)`

Comment: pls run `ls -l /var/www/html`

Comment: `iskog@iskog-server:/etc/apache2$ ls -l /var/www/html
total 8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 iskog iskog 32 mars  26 13:47 index.html
-rwxrwxrwx 1 iskog iskog 28 mars  26 13:46 index.php`

Comment: do this also `id -Gn`

Comment: Try this `sudo chown -R iskog:www-data /var/www/html`, then add u to `grp www-data`, `sudo gpasswd -a iskog www-data`

Comment: I've runned all the commands, still "403 Forbidden" (also restared apache by `service apache2 restart`) ; I try a reboot

Comment: a reboot should fix it or logout...

Comment: 403 forbidden... but something seems strange, when I stop apache by service apache2 stop ; I can access the 403 forbidden. wut ?
EDIT : `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      918/lighttpd`
lighttpd is running on port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved !

I ran `netstat -putan` and I saw that **lighttpd was running on port 80 next to apache**, due to the 403 forbidden : 
[...] 
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      918/lighttpd`
[...] 
You can also see if a http server is running by stopping apache `sudo service apache2 stop` and see if http://localhost is up or not. If not, look to the comments of George (by the way thx :D) it might help you 
Simply remove lighttpd by `apt-get remove lighttpd*` 
I hope this will help some of you c: